# Upload video to youtube from tizen

Tags: youtube-api, tizen

I'm trying to upload video form tizen to the youtube account. I'm getting an error saying "No file found in request". Any suggestions to implement this?

I'm following the procedure from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading). I completed till 3. Video's from my desktop is uploaded properly. But the same is not working with device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you're performing the upload from the context of a web browser or as an application that's just making HTTP requests. (I'm not familiar with the Tizen platform.)

If you're just writing an application that makes HTTP requests, then don't try to replicate the browser-based upload flow from your app. Instead, you could use the [direct upload](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading) or [resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_resumable_uploads) flows.

If you're writing a web application and it's failing in the Tizen browser and working on a desktop browser, then that sounds like a bug in the Tizen browser.

Comment: I tried to implement direct upload. but i'm getting error as bad request. do you have any idea how it should be implemented. I believe i'm making some mistake in xml data. do have any sample for the direct upload (ajax format).

Comment: There's an XML protocol level sample of doing a direct upload at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading

Comment: yeah.. i'm sending the xml.. But i'm not sure of the format.. Can you gimme a working sample for that..

Comment: A working example of what a complete HTTP request looks like is found in the documentation page that I linked to. If you're asking for JavaScript code to perform the upload, no, that's not something I can provide.

Comment: Thanks jeff... I've already gone through the documentation and couldn't achieve anything.. I'm not asking for a complete code.. I want information on what should go where.. Like header, data and so on for the ajax request..

Comment: Thanks jeff.. I already know that the request looks like that and tried.. What i'm asking here is what should go where? like which one should be in header and which one should be in data component and so on..

Comment: The documentation presents that info via a standard HTTP request example—everything at the start of an example until the first double-newline is part of the HTTP request header (the header names are before the colon, and values follow the colon), and then after the double-newline comes the HTTP request body.

Comment: You mean the content before first boundary string("--f93dcbA3") is in header and other in body?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean. The body in this case is a MIME multipart body: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

Comment: Thanks jeff... I can able to upload the video through direct upload..  But after processing i got Failed(unable to convert video) in youtube.. And also there is no response from youtube

Comment: Then you're not uploading the entire video file (maybe your Content-Length is set too low?), or your video file is invalid.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. i completed in an hour after commenting here. Yeah one of the reason is content-length.